# FFMPEG expand limited range to full range

Tags: ffmpeg

I am working on a recipe to convert Avid DNxHD files which are rec.709 "legal" range (15-235 in 8bpc) to .png files which are "full" range (0-255). In looking around it seems that "colorspace" could do this, but I am quite new to FFMPEG filters and I can't seem to get it to work... I've looked all over the place but not found a solution to this simple question

`-i video.mov -fv yadif=0:0:0,colorspace=srgb transcode_%04d.png` just throws an error, and I assume I just don't know the proper syntax (no real example for this in the manual, that I could find).

Separately i thought this might work: `-i video.mov -vf yadif=0:0:0,scale=in_range=tv:out_range=full transcode_%04d.png`. This runs without complaining, but the output .png's are still in legal range.

Comment: How are you checking pixel values?

Comment: @Gyan Pulling into After Effects and color sampling. I've got a file exported from Avid as legal, and another as full to compare against.

Comment: Take an input which has pure white or black in it and run: `ffmpeg -i video.mov -vf trim=end_frame=1,signalstats@pre,format=rgb24,signalstats@post  test.png` I assume the black/white portion is visible in the first frame. If not, add `-ss X` before `-i` where X should be a timestamp of a frame that has white/black in it. Share log. Add `2> log.txt` at end of cmd to generate it.

Comment: @Guyan I figured it out if you're interested! I just didn't fully understand filter chaining syntax in ffmpeg, and didn't realize that ffmpeg will automatically default to "full" range as long as I tell it that the source is "tv"...

Comment: That's not correct. Output range is determined by destination pixel format, which in turn depends on the pixel formats the encoder allows. `full` is not an automatic outcome.

Comment: @Gyan so I guess because I'm going to .png it is "automatically" working.

Answer (score 1):

Whelp finally figured this one out when I stumbled across the answer in another forum. Pretty simple really, just needed to study  up on [filtergraphs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1). And for the record bwdif deinterlacing is FAR better than yadif! Not sure why anyone even recommends yadif anymore with bwdif out there...

`-i inputfile -vf bwdif=0:0:0,scale=in_range=tv outputfile.mov`